# Testing recompose's HOC with enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, recompose

How can I test (with `jest`+`enzyme`) the following code that uses `recompose` for creating a HoC:

```
import {compose, withState, withHandlers} from 'recompose'

const addCounting = compose(
  withState('counter', 'setCounter', 0),
  withHandlers({
    increment: ({ setCounter }) => () => setCounter(n => n + 1),
    decrement: ({ setCounter }) => () =>  setCounter(n => n - 1),
    reset: ({ setCounter }) => () => setCounter(0)
  })
)
```

When performing shallow render, I have access to `counter` and `setCounter` properties, like so:

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'

const WithCounting = addCounting(EmptyComponent)
const wrapper = shallow(<WithCounting />)

wrapper.props().setCounter(1)
expect(wrapper.props().counter).toEqual(1)
```

The big question is, how can I access the handlers (`increment`, `decrement` and `reset`) and call them? They do not appear in the `wrapper.props()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you can access the props by finding the instance first:

```
const EmptyComponent = () => null;
const WithCounting = addCounting(props => <EmptyComponent {...props} />);
const wrapper = mount(<WithCounting />);

wrapper.find(EmptyComponent).props().setCounter(1);
expect(wrapper.find(EmptyComponent).props().counter).toEqual(1);
```